# computed function runs in one component but not in another

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

I have several components on a page, and I find that updates to a parent object are reflected in one of the components, but not in the other.

The main page, `PatientEditor.vue` includes these components:

```
                <notes-editor v-model="pt" />
                <chart-completion v-model="pt" arrange="horiz" />
```

and has this script:

```
module.exports = {
  props: ["pt"]
};
```

So, the `pt` object is in the parent, and it is passed to several components as a `v-model`

The component `ChartCompletion.vue` works well. It has these in it.

```
module.exports = {
  props: ["value", "arrange"],

  computed: {
    completed_notes: function() {
      return this.value.notes.filter(function(note) {
        return note.signed_at;
      }).length;
    },
```

My problem child, however is the `NotesEditor.vue` template which contains the following:

```
module.exports = {
  props: ["value"],

  computed: {
    completed_notes: function() {
      return this.value.notes.filter(function(note) {
        return note.signed_at;
      }).length;
    }
  },
```

Not sure if it's important, but the `notes` object is populated from an ajax call in another component like this:

```
      this.value.notes.splice(0, this.value.notes.length, ...response.body.notes);
      this.$emit("input", this.value);
```

Sooooo, here's the problem.

When `this.value.notes` is updated, the results are seen in the `ChartCompletion` component, but they are not seen in the `NotesEditor` component. When I use the Vue debugger in chrome, I can see that the notes object is changed, but, for some reason, the computed property doesn't re-fire, even though it has the identical definition in the `ChartCompletion` component. Also, I have a `v-for` in `NotesEditor` that doesn't change either.

What is the best way to debug this?

**EDIT 1 -- including the `NotesEditor` component**

```
<template>
  <span>
    <table class="table">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>Date</th>
          <th>Status</th>
          <th>Audio</th>
          <th>Text</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr v-for="n in value.notes" :key="n.id">
          <th>{{n.created_at}}</th>
          <td>{{n.note_status_id}}</td>
          <td>
            <span v-if="n.audio_length > 0">
              <audio controls="controls" preload="none">
                <source :src="audioURL(n.id)" type="audio/webm"> Your browser does not support the audio element.
              </audio>
              ({{n.audio_length}}s)
            </span>
            <span v-else>
              None
            </span>
          </td>
          <td>
            <span v-if="n.note_text">
              <button data-toggle="tooltip" :title="n.note_text" class="btn btn-outline-primary btn-sm" @click.prevent="openChartEditor(n.id)">
                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-edit"></span> Edit Note ({{ n.note_text.length }} chars)
              </button>
            </span>
            <span v-else>
              <button class="btn btn-primary btn-sm" @click.prevent="openChartEditor(n.id)">
                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil"></span> Create Note
              </button>
            </span>
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td colspan="3">
            <record v-model="value" />
          </td>
          <td>
            <button class="btn btn-primary" @click.prevent="openChartEditor(0)">
              <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil"></span> Create Note
            </button>
          </td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </span>
</template>


<script>
module.exports = {
  props: ["value"],

  data: function() {
    return {
      sendFaxWorking: false
    };
  },

  computed: {
    completed_notes: function() {
      return this.value.notes.filter(function(note) {
        return note.signed_at;
      }).length;
    }
  },

  methods: {
    audioURL: function(id) {
      return "/notes/getAudio/" + id;
    },

    openChartEditor: function(id) {
      this.$root.$emit("showEditor", id);
    }
  }
};
</script>

<style>
audio {
  vertical-align: middle;
  border: 0;
  margin: 0;
}
</style>
```

Comment: does your `v-for` use some `:key=` ? also AFAIK  `this.value.notes.splice(` mutates the prop, instead create a new one which you then `$emit`

Comment: Are the computed properties actually used in both components? They're lazy-evaluated, so they'll only be updated if they're needed

Comment: actually I can not reproduce your issue(quick try https://jsfiddle.net/maxsinev/dp86Lzyu/) but what I can say about your code is - don't change `this.value.notes`(because it's a field of prop!) in a child component you need another component where `notes` will be passed as `v-model` separately and you should do something like `this.$emit('input', response.body.notes)`. Or you can use Vuex to avoid working with kind of a deep nesting of props and code duplication.

Comment: @birdspider - the `v-for` does use `:key` and it does work correctly the first time. It just doesn't update; According to https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/list.html#Array-Change-Detection, it would seem that splice is a wrapped function and should cause notification. In fact, it does notify in the `ChartCompletion` component, just not in the `NotesEditor` component.

Comment: @aurumpotestasest - The computed properties are identically defined in both components, and it does work in `ChartCompletion`

Comment: @mankowitz it don't think this has to do with array change detection per se, but with a) mutating a prop, b) additionally emitting an input;  take a look at https://jsfiddle.net/dp86Lzyu/14/ (forked of Max Sinev's fiddle)

Comment: @MaxSinev - just to be clear, `this.value` is not the same as `this.value.notes`, so I can't emit just the notes. I suppose I could create a new object as a clone of this.value, but I'm not sure what the benefit is, since, as an object, it is not automatically propagated back to the parent until I `$emit`

Comment: @mankowitz yes it is not the same, but `value` contains `notes`. you pass `value` by reference to child component and as best practice you shouldn't change the internal values of your prop(or prop itself). Honestly `$emit` is do nothing in your case and this is indicator of some inconsistency, for example, you can remove `$emit` and it will work as before(you can try it in my fiddle above).

Comment: @MaxSinev - Mind Blown. Didn't realize that would work without the `$emit`. Anyway, I removed all of the $emit statments, and the `NotesEditor` component still fails to update the `v-for` and the computed property, even though the `ChartCompletion` component updates normally and the vue debugger shows changes in the object. I'll include the whole `NotesEditor` template in the question, if that helps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think this is a good answer, but it does work. I added a watcher function that calls `$forceUpdate()`

```
  mounted: function() {
    this.$watch("value.notes", this.$forceUpdate);
  },
```